# How to set a particular animation for each button when they pressed in Swift for ios 11

Tags: ios, swift

It's a two-sided game i want different animation took place for each opponent i want X using fade in animation and Y to fade out. Also i created its buttons by Tagging them (which makes it easier to coding). Sorry if it seems a little complicated. anyway I've use this

```
UIImage.animate(withDuration:1, animation: { self.image.alpha = 1)
```

for a single object and it works fine but don't know how to make this for different buttons which tagged by numbers.

ios11, swift 4, xcode

Comment: What;s the question? Give us more code and tell us what is exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to iOS development, so sorry in advance; maybe connect one of the buttons to an `IBAction`, create a separate animation function and then call it within the `IBAction` using the Swift equivalent of `[self animationFunc]`? Again, I am very new to this.